# MySQL selecting rows that exactly match categories selected using checkboxes

Tags: mysql

I have three checkboxes and an additional option to show only intersection

checkboxes

1. Green
2. Sustainable
3. Social

and another checkbox that says : check to show intersection

So when someone selects Green, they need to see all green products, if they select Green and Social they'll see all products that have either green tag or social tag attached, this can be done simple using WHERE product_category_id IN (1,11) and so on.

Now when someone checks Green and Social and the additional checkbox to show only intersection i want to only display the products have eaxactly both tags assigned. i.e just the ones that have both green and social label and ignore the rest.

From the tables below for green and Social it should return

```
id          organisation_name
-----------------------------------------------
3221        Nederlandse Watershapsbank NV
```

and if someone selects green, sustainable and social along with the intersect option they should see only:

```
id        organisation_name
--------------------------------
21        Uppsalahem AB
```

Product table

```
id         issuer
-------------------------
1          1   
11         1741 
21         21  
31         31  
41         3221
51         51
```

Organisation table

```
id          organisation_name
----------------------------------------
1           Nordic Investment Bank
21          Uppsalahem AB
31          Stangastaden
51          European Investment Bank
1741        Global Infrastructure Partners
3221        Nederlandse Watershapsbank NV
```

Item categories table

```
id          product_id      product_category_id
--------------------------------------------------
1           1               1
2           11              1
3           21              1
4           31              1
5           41              1
5           41              61
6           51              1
6           51              11
6           21              61
6           21              11
```

Item categories table

```
id          product_category_name
--------------------------------------
1           Green      
11          Sustainable
61          Social
```

SQL:

```
SELECT Products.id,
Organisation.organisation_name, 
ProductCategory.product_category_id, 
ProductCategory.product_id  
FROM `Products`  
LEFT JOIN `product_category` `ProductCategory` ON ProductCategory.product_id=Products.id  
LEFT JOIN `organisation` `Organisation` ON Organisation.id=Products.issuer 
LEFT JOIN `categories` `Categories` ON Categories.id=ProductCategory.product_category_id 
WHERE `ProductCategory`.`product_category_id` IN (1, 11)  
GROUP BY Products.id  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
ORDER BY Products.id ASC;
```

Comment: You need to build the query dynamically in your code.

Comment: You *can* build your query dynamically, but I'd be tempted to handle the filtering in the presentation layer. Here's a link to some examples of presentation layer filtering... https://isotope.metafizzy.co/extras.html

Comment: Might be a good solution for smaller datasets @Strawberry for the larger datasets iám more tempted to do it on the database with correct indexing.

Comment: well the code is dynamic i will be passing the checkbox values through to the query, i am not too worried about presentation / model logic, i just need the raw MYSQL query to be able to do this and i can pass the values through thats not an issue. thanks.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I agree in principle. But what constitutes a larger data set is debatable.

Comment: @bharath i believe this is called "relational division" what you want search Stackoverflow or Google you should find some examples.

Comment: For further help, I would suggest you see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Although I would probably do this in the presentation layer, the logic that you're looking for is as follows:

`...GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ...) = n`

Where:

DISTINCT is optional but can do no harm

and

n is equal to the number of arguments in IN()

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back on this, i've updated the question and added the sql in, i tried the group by and having, but it doesn't work, can you see what's not right please? thanks a ton again.

Comment: i think the issue here is around the group by, i am not able to group by product_category_id?